# Connecting a 20 amps battery charger to an 18 amps source

Tags: current, battery-charging, inverter

I have an inverter with a 20 amps DC battery charger (AC to DC ). I need to a connect the ac Generator output to the ac input of the inverter. The thing is that the generator can provide a maximum current of 18 amps. So, now since the battery charger in the inverter charges the battery at 20 amps, will it be a problem now ? Or is it just that the battery will be charged at a slower pace as just 18 amps would be available to the charger ?

Comment: I doubt if the battery charger is a linear regulator or that the a.c. supply and d.c. battery charging voltages are the same. So, compare the power capacity versus the power requirement, rather than the current. If it is still too little, it is quite hard to say what will happen without any reference to the design of the battery charger. Also worth noting is that this site is for questions about *electronic design*, not the use of consumer electronic devices.

Comment: This is a really BADLY written question.  1) An inverter normally converts DC battery power to AC.  How are you connecting the AC output of the generator to the inverter?  2) 18 Amps at WHAT voltage?  12 Vdc? 120 Vac? 230 Vac?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work perfectly fine if the voltage from the AC generator is 110 or 220 Volts

20 amps at 12 volts is 240 Watts. This is the charging power.

18 amps at 110 volts AC is 1.98 kW

Answer (score 0):

If the battery charger's AC input is marked 20 amps, it should not be connected to an AC supply that is rated for 18 amps. The load will take the current that it is designed to take and the supply will not necessarily limit the current except by tripping a circuit breaker or blowing a fuse. The circuit breaker or fuse is supposed to prevent components of the source from overheating, but it is not a good idea to plug in more than the source is rated for and wait for the source to shut it off.